# How to update or save a specific field only in CakePHP 3.0?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to update or save a specific field of a table in Cakephp 3.0. I tried [Updating Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#updating-data) from the Cakebook and it is saving the data but problem is that it is also saving the **modified** field assigned as datetime in database. I do not want to save this field in that case. How do i do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update only one field on Cakephp 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218488/update-only-one-field-on-cakephp-3)

Comment: Yeah but using the connection manager class is not necessary IMO. Docs should include a better example @ http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/timestamp.html .

Comment: @ndm, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218488/update-only-one-field-on-cakephp-3 can solve the problem but have to load the table instance again using **TableResigtry** in same controller. So i do not need to load it in the same controller as we can get the instance by default.

Comment: You don't have to load the table again, you can just use the one you already have, after all, that's just example code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But before asking, i did try but no luck `$query = $this->Posts->query();
            $post = $query->update()->set(['field' => $newfield])->where(['id' => $id])->execute();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you don't want callbacks to be triggered, just use `updateAll()`

```
$table->updateAll(['field' => $newValue], ['id' => $entityId]);
```

Comment: Works great, but how about an associated field? e.g. `$this->Users->updateAll(...);` is fine, but if Users belongsTo Groups, in the UsersController `$this->Users->Groups->updateAll(['field'=>$data1],[$id=>$data2])` tries to work but the data comes out mangled. `UPDATE groups SET field = :c0 WHERE = :c1`